# I need help decoding this regular expression from sprockets

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I need help decoding this regular expression from sprockets. I am not sure what this matches but if someone give give me some hints or starting points.

```
HEADER_PATTERN = /
\A (
  (?m:\s*) (
   (\/\* (?m:.*?) \*\/) |
   (\#\#\# (?m:.*?) \#\#\#) |
   (\/\/ .* \n?)+ |
   (\# .* \n?)+
  )
 )+
/x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HEADER_PATTERN = /
\A (                             # Start of string
  (?m:\s*) (                     # Match optional whitespace
   (\/\* (?m:.*?) \*\/) |        # Either match /* (any characters, lazily) */
   (\#\#\# (?m:.*?) \#\#\#) |    # or ### (any characters, lazily) ###
   (\/\/ .* \n?)+ |              # or // (any characters except newlines) until optional newline (one or more)
   (\# .* \n?)+                  # or # (any characters except newlines) until optional newline (one or more)
  )
 )+                              # once or more
/x
```

`(?m:...)` allows the dot inside this sub-expression also to match newline characters which is usually doesn't. (This is a Ruby specialty; nearly all other regex flavors use `(?s:...)` for this)

So it seems this regex matches block comments or line comments at the start of a file/string.

Answer (score 2):

```
\A
```

Anchor to the start of the string

```
(
```

Starts a group which wraps the entire string. It ends with `)+` so this matches 1 or more instances.

```
(?m:\s*)
```

Turns on the multiline flag for this atom, and matches zero or more "space" characters (e.g. space, vertical tab, horizontal tab, newline, or carriage return). I have no idea why they turn on the multiline flag here since that doesn't affect the `\s` escape.

```
(\/\* (?m:.*?) \*\/)
```

The first bit `\/` matches the `/` char (escaped because `/` is the delimiter for the regex). `\*` matches the `*` char. The space can be ignored because of the `x` modifier. Then it turns on the multiline flag again for `.*?`, which makes `.` match newlines. The `?` here makes the `*` modifier non-greedy, so it matches any character, but only as few as it takes to make the rest of the pattern match. It then follows with a `*`, and a `/`. In other words, it matches a C-style comment (`/* text */`)

```
|
```

or

```
(\#\#\# (?m:.*?) \#\#\#)
```

Match any text surrounded by `###`, e.g. `### something ###`. Again the use of the multiline modifier with `.`, and the non-greedy match so it stops matching as soon as `###` matches something. The `#` characters are escaped because of the `x` modifier.

```
|
```

or

```
(\/\/ .* \n?)+
```

Match `//`, followed by any text, followed by an optional newline. I guess the newline is optional in case this is the end of the string. The lack of the multiline modifier makes `.` not match newlines. This basically matches `//` followed by anything, up until the end of the line.

```
|
```

or

```
(\# .* \n?)+
```

Match `#`, followed by any text, followed by an optional newline. Same thing as the previous pattern but using `#` instead of `//`. Note that the earlier `###` pattern takes precedence because it's earlier, so if text matches the `###` pattern it won't be matched by this one.

And finally, the whole thing uses the `x` modifier, so spaces, newlines, and any text after `#` in the pattern is ignored (this is why it is written across multiple lines). That's just for readability.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yes, but the first atom was `(?m:\s*)`, which has no dot. I mentioned in the second usage of `(?m:...)` that the multiline flag makes `.` match newlines, and it makes sense there, but the `\s*` isn't affected by this flag.